# Why I cannot override method wait() in Java?

Tags: java

I find the method `wait()` in the class `Object`.
It is final which means that this method cannot be overriden.
Any ideas why it's final?

Comment: Because it is... and it would probably be a horrendously bad idea to override it.

Comment: why do you really want to override it?

Comment: Im trying to understand class Object.

Comment: In the source, `wait()` is marked as `native`.  That means the body isn't written in Java but is built into the JVM (or the compiler).  The implementation of that, `notify()`, and `notifyAll()` are probably tightly built into the fabric of the JVM, and overriding them would likely break lots of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Flavio - it's actually a very good question.

The reason *you* can't override it, of course, is that the designers made it "final".

A couple of potential reasons for this decision:

- You don't want people to mess with the semantics of a fundamental operation on a fundamental class (class "Object").
- Since it's "final", compilers can optimize performance (save a few cycles) by in-lining "wait()"
- "final" increases the security of the Java object model by preventing malicious code from exploiting "wait()".

Comment: It is not `protected`.

Comment: Fair enough.  Changed.  Per the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not designed to be overriden, that's why. The method `wait()` calls `wait(long timeout)` which is `final` and `native`. So the latter is not supposed to be overriden and the no-paremeter version is just `final` so it is not supposed to be overriden too.

Answer (score 0):

If you override a **very** basic functionality available for all `Object`s then it is highly likely that you will blow up your software or ruin your colleague's day.

If you check the documentation of `wait()`:

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

it turns out that it works in tandem with `notify()` and `notifyAll()` so you can't change it without altering their functionality. Not to mention the dozens of concurrent libraries using those methods.

Answer (score -1):

It has a fairly concrete implementation that does not need to be modified. The logic behind `wait()` should be synonymous across all objects