# Why Can't I Create a Static Method Called wait()?

Tags: java

Example code:

```
class A {
    static void wait(){}
}
```

It seems as if there shouldn't be a problem with compiling this, but it won't compile. Please note that the method is static.

Compiler error:

```
A.java:2: error: wait() in A cannot override wait() in Object
    static void wait(){}
                ^
  overriding method is static
1 error
```

Why is it even trying to override `wait()` in `Object` when it is a static method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I cannot override method wait() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974045/why-i-cannot-override-method-wait-in-java)

Comment: @Rao Not a duplicate because the method is static.

Answer (score 3):

If you were allowed write a static method `wait()` with the same signature as the non-static `Object.wait()` method, which method should be called in the following code:

```
A a = new A();
a.wait();
```

would it be the `wait()` method of the instance inherited from `Object` ort the static `wait()` method from Class *A*? So from the compiler's point of of view this is not distinguishable and therefore there is no difference between a static method and a non-static method of the same class.

Which means in the consequence that the non-static final method cannot be overwritten by a method with the same signature, no matter if this overwriting method is static or not.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the method signature of `Object.wait()`, btw there are more overloaded methods in `Object`:

```
public final void wait()
```

A **final** method *cannot* be overridden by child/sub class.

In method signature, modifier like `static` is not taken into account.

- method name
- parameters
- type of parameters
- order of parameters

As per new specification, now method return type is also a part of method signature.

Answer (score 2):

This is the declaration for java.lang.Object.wait() method

```
public final void wait().
```

As it states, it is a final method which means you cannot override it.

It does not matter whether you try declare the method as static since you already inherit wait() method from the class Object. What you are trying to do here is modify the method with the 'static' keyword.